# Is there a way to destructure a freezeDelegatedNft?

Tags: metaplex, metaplex-js, freeze-token-account

I am looking for a way to destructure a freezeDelegatedNft so I can combine it with another transaction.

This is what I have currently:

```
await metaplex.tokens().approveDelegateAuthority({
  mintAddress: nftMint,
  delegateAuthority: wallet.publicKey,
});

await metaplex
  .nfts()
  .freezeDelegatedNft({ mintAddress: nftMint, delegateAuthority: wallet });

const tx = SystemProgram.transfer({
  fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
  toPubkey: new PublicKey("A1nC3ZUM7aTML57yuVJ269fBiT3aBH6uqwX23poypA82"),
  lamports: transferAmount,
});

const transaction = new Transaction().add(tx);
...
```

What I'm looking for:

```
await metaplex.tokens().approveDelegateAuthority({
  mintAddress: nftMint,
  delegateAuthority: wallet.publicKey,
});

const tx2 = await metaplex
  .nfts()
  .freezeDelegatedNft({ mintAddress: nftMint, delegateAuthority: wallet });

const tx1 = SystemProgram.transfer({
  fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
  toPubkey: new PublicKey("A1nC3ZUM7aTML57yuVJ269fBiT3aBH6uqwX23poypA82"),
  lamports: transferAmount,
});

const transaction = new Transaction().add(tx, tx2);
...
```

Is there a way to implement this with Metaplex currently?
Any response would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: Really sorry for the prev answer but i need some clarification here. I am not sure if there exists a freezeDelegatedAccount. and according to the code snippets shared by you it looks like you want the ix's and want to combine it in one tx. Let me know if i am incorrect

Comment: @Pratik.js Yeah sorry, I mixed up freezeDelegatedAccount with freezeDelegatedNft
Should be updated now :)

Answer (score -1):

puedo explicarte cómo desestructurar o descomponer un NFT (Non-Fungible Token) en general.

Un NFT es un activo digital único registrado en una cadena de bloques, como Ethereum. Para desestructurar un NFT, es necesario tener acceso al contrato inteligente que lo respalda y seguir los pasos proporcionados por dicho contrato.

A continuación, te proporciono una guía general sobre cómo desestructurar un NFT en Ethereum:

1. Identifica el contrato inteligente: Para desestructurar un NFT, necesitas identificar el contrato inteligente asociado al NFT en cuestión. Puedes obtener esta información a través del explorador de bloques de Ethereum o consultando el proyecto o plataforma que emitió el NFT.
2. Accede al contrato inteligente: Para interactuar con el contrato inteligente, necesitarás una billetera de Ethereum compatible. Puedes usar aplicaciones como MetaMask o MyEtherWallet para conectarte a la cadena de bloques.
3. Conecta tu billetera al contrato inteligente: Utilizando tu billetera, conecta tu cuenta a la interfaz del contrato inteligente. Esto te permitirá interactuar con las funciones específicas del contrato.
4. Utiliza la función de desestructuración: Dependiendo de cómo esté diseñado el contrato inteligente, es posible que incluya una función específica para desestructurar o transferir la propiedad del NFT. Esta función puede tener un nombre como "transfer" o "send".
5. Sigue las instrucciones proporcionadas: Una vez que hayas localizado la función de desestructuración, sigue las instrucciones proporcionadas por el contrato inteligente. Esto puede implicar proporcionar la dirección del destinatario al que deseas transferir el NFT y confirmar la transacción.

Recuerda que los pasos pueden variar dependiendo del contrato inteligente y la plataforma que emitió el NFT. Si el NFT en cuestión pertenece a un estándar o protocolo específico, te recomendaría consultar la documentación o los recursos proporcionados por ese estándar o protocolo para obtener instrucciones más precisas.

Es importante tener en cuenta que la información
es posible que haya nuevas actualizaciones o desarrollos en el espacio de los NFT. Te sugiero verificar la documentación y los recursos más recientes relacionados con el NFT en cuestión para obtener información actualizada.

Comment: Please answer in english